# Como especificar aos motores de busca atualização de um documento HTML?

Tags: html5, seo, web-crawler

De acordo com [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) usando a tag `<time></time>` com atributo `datetime` `<time datetime="yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"></time>`, permite que os mecanismos de busca saibam a data de criação do documento, apresentando então essa informação, no Rich Snippet das pesquisas.

É possível indicar a data de atualização do mesmo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode construir seu `sitemap.xml` usando a tag `<changefreq></changefreq>` para dizer aos `crawlers` que vc quer que seu conteúdo seja reindexado, de hora em hora, todo dia, ou semanalmente por exemplo.

Aqui vc pode ver o protocolo completo e recomendado para vc construir seu `sitemap`, repare que vc pode determinar a regularidade com que o seu conteúdo é reindexado: https://www.sitemaps.org/pt_BR/protocol.html

A freqüência com que a página é alterada. Esse valor fornece informações gerais para os mecanismos de pesquisa e pode ser que ele não corresponda exatamente à freqüência de indexação da página. Os valores válidos são:

- always
- hourly
- daily
- weekly
- monthly
- anual
- never

O valor "always" deve ser usado para descrever os documentos que sempre são alterados quando acessados. O valor "never" deve ser usado para descrever os URLs arquivados.

***Observe que o valor dessa tag é considerado uma `dica` e não um comando.***

Apesar de não se pode ter totalmente certeza de que o Google vai considerar essa tag para reindexar seu conteúdo `weekly` ou `daily` por exemplo

> "Se as páginas do site estiverem devidamente vinculadas, o normal será
>   nossos rastreadores da Web conseguirem detectar a maior parte de seu
>   site.", mas "O uso do sitemap não garante que todos os itens nele
>   serão rastreados e indexados, pois os processos do Google têm como
>   base algoritmos complexos para programar o rastreamento. No entanto, o
>   sitemap beneficia o site na maioria dos casos, e você nunca será
>   penalizado por usá-lo."

Fonte: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=pt-BR

---

Tirando isso, para vc não ficar totalmente não mão do `sitemap`, em um caso de **urgência** vc pode solicitar manualmente a reindexação de uma URL. Por exemplo se vc fizer uma atualização de segurança na página de contatos vc pode solicitar ao Google que faça uma reindexação da sua página. Aqui vc pode se informar mais sobre isso: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=pt-BR

Para adicionar manualmente uma URL *(pesquise tb "Fetch as Google")*: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?

Para indexar pelo Search Console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vc ainda pode solicitar a reindexação do site inteiro pelo Serch Console!**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]